# How to get xml from many records?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

So I have the below that will allow me to get xml from one record in the `Products` table.

However, I need to to be able to get the XML from ALL records in the `Products` table, along with its `ProductId`.

I'm confused on how to start this.

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML =
    (SELECT ProductsXML
     FROM Products
     WHERE ProductId= 1)
SELECT 
    a.b.value('@upccode','int') as UPC,
    a.b.value('@dateadded','date') as DateAdded
FROM
    @MyXML.nodes('xml/Product/UPC')a(b);
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Test Data:

```
ProductId: 1
ProductsXML:
<xml>
        <Product>
            <UPC upccode="1237" dateadded="10/9/2012"/>
            <UPC upccode="1236" dateadded="10/8/2012"/>
            <UPC upccode="1235" dateadded="10/7/2012"/>
            <UPC upccode="1234" dateadded="10/6/2012"/>
        </Product>
    </xml>

ProductId: 2
ProductsXML:
<xml>
        <Product>
            <UPC upccode="9876" dateadded="9/9/2012"/>
            <UPC upccode="9877" dateadded="9/8/2012"/>
            <UPC upccode="0998" dateadded="9/7/2012"/>
            <UPC upccode="7877" dateadded="9/6/2012"/>
        </Product>
    </xml>
```

The Result I'm looking for is something like this:

```
ProductId      UPC        DateAdded
---------      ---        ---------
1              1237       10/9/2012
1              1236       10/8/2012
....
2              9876       9/9/2012
2              9877       9/8/2012
```

Right now I can get the above but ONLY by specifying one `PoductId` at a time. I want to be able to run all of the `Products' without specifying each entry.

Comment: Can you add some data to test? wich version of SQLServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this.

```
SELECT ProductId,
    a.b.value('@upccode','int') as UPC,
    a.b.value('@dateadded','date') as DateAdded
FROM Products
  CROSS APPLY ProductsXML.nodes('xml/Product/UPC')a(b);
```

There is no need to have a XML variable in there. Query the `Products` table directly and use `CROSS APPLY` against `ProductsXML` field to shred your XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
hi u can try using Linq to xml to create an entity from the xml, see the sample code below


XDocument somedoc = XDocument.Load("your xml path");


var somelist = from somevariable in somedoc.Descendants("Product")
               select new Product {
                                    UPC = somevariable.Attribute("upccode").value
                                    DateAdded = somevariable.Attribute("dateadded").value
                                  }

so now somelist is  a collection thru which u can iterate and add to List<Product>, create product b4 u start tryinh this
```